# Disabling any and all forms of write buffering and write caching

Tags: debian, kernel, cache

I have recently discovered that the cause of my systems' instability is that Linux is buffering writes, and it is doing so for all devices of any form, and it is not caring how much destruction it is causing when it overflows and OOM kills literally every running process.

How do I disable this, system-wide, and not in userspace? This has caused so many problems, I just want it gone at this point.

```
CPU: Intel i7-3820QM
RAM: 4x8 GiB DDR3-1600
GPU 0: Intel HD Graphics 4000
GPU 1: nVidia Quadro K2000M 2 GB (No drivers are present, so it's effective irrelevant.)
```

Any help would be appreciated, and if I have to compile a kernel, I can do that.

Comment: You would be better off finding out what is using all your RAM and fixing it (or change your usage patterns) so that you don't run out of memory.  BTW, your understanding of what is happening is inaccurate - caching will NEVER cause an OOM error as the kernel will evict cached pages / flush write buffers whenever a program needs more RAM. Cache, both read and write, only ever uses RAM that isn't needed by a program.   You should seriously consider adding some swap space (perhaps using [zswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap) or [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram)).

Comment: That's the thing, nothing but the cache is using it. I can very quickly cause it by having KDE search a drive for a file. You see the cache and buffers balloon, and then OOM happens, and I get dumped back to SDDM.

Comment: that's probably wasteful memory usage or memory leaks in whatever KDE program you're using to do the search, not caching.  try `find` on the command line.  don't blame the kernel for application bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Create e.g. `/etc/sysctl.d/disable_dirty_cache.conf` (the name is arbitrary, it just has to end with `.conf`), reboot:

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
```

Not tested, not even sure it's gonna work, if it doesn't increase the values to say 4096 or something bigger. This has the potential to completely destroy your write performance and severely increase file fragmentation. Write buffers are essential for a multitasking OS.

> OOM kills literally every running process.

Maybe you could address the root issue by e.g.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install earlyoom
sudo systemctl enable --now earlyoom
```

Comment: I won't be installing EarlyOOM, it was the cause of my last memory issue. Every time I got to 4 GB of RAM left, it killed most of my processes.

Edit because the Enter key is bound to "Post": Does this stop caching on TTYs and serial devices? Those do it too. Basically, if it's in `/dev`, it's being cached.

Comment: @AshleighTheCutie are you sure about the latter? Serial devices and ttys aren’t supposed to be cached.

Comment: I've been using `earlyoom` for several years and lost 0 applications to it. Not sure how it's set up for you, it mustn't kill processes when you've got 4GB of RAM left unless you've got like 40GB of RAM and you've set it up to kill processes when 10% of RAM is available which is very weird. For instance in Fedora it's set up by default not to do anything unless you've got just 400MB left which is too little in this day and age. I suspect you've got `tmpfs` mounted as well, so your situation could be exacerbated by the presence of the large volume of temporary files.

Comment: Artem: I have 32 GB, so 3.2 GB, sorry. I also just checked `tmpfs` mounts, and collectively, they all are under 50 MB total usage. It's not `tmpfs`. I will try to verify the serial device caching once my phone is ready to have it's ROM reflashed; if it instantly "completes" and then my OS dies, we'll know. [Edit: i swear I can spell.]

Comment: The fact that your running tasks consume over 90% of RAM doesn't inspire confidence - I mean you should consider expanding your RAM or adding SWAP/ZSWAP but then I've seen worse situations. With that much RAM being occupied the kernel starts to evict read cache buffers and that often tanks performance.

Comment: I can't use Swap, as that nukes the write cache, and 32 GB is the max the system can have. Granted, I no longer do those tasks, but I can't trust EarlyOOM to not be daft and kill things without warning. OOM is working fine; it sees less than 0K free RAM, and kills tasks. That is it's job. If the write cache wasn't eating 24 GB of RAM, I'd be fine. Edit: Well, I'd rather have a stable but slow machine over a fast but untrustable machine.

Comment: Write cache cannot possibly eat that much memory, running applications code (RSS) takes precedence over any forms of caching. If `earlyoom` kills your tasks when less than 3.2GB of RAM is available, it means your write cache is much less than that. Here's how it's set up here and I cannot complain:

Comment: `EARLYOOM_ARGS="-r 0 -m 4 -M 409600 --prefer '^(Web Content|Isolated Web Co)$' --avoid '^(dnf|packagekitd|gnome-shell|gnome-session-c|gnome-session-b|lightdm|sddm|sddm-helper|gdm|gdm-wayland-ses|gdm-session-wor|gdm-x-session|Xorg|Xwayland|systemd|systemd-
logind|dbus-daemon|dbus-broker|cinnamon|cinnamon-sessio|kwin_x11|kwin_wayland|plasmashell|ksmserver|plasma_session|startplasma-way|xfce4-session|mate-session|marco|lxqt-session|openbox|cryptsetup)$'"`

Comment: [EDIT: Why does formatting not exist in this comment system?] `free -m`:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31661        6975         383        2344       24302       21875

Comment: `21875MB` of available RAM, you're doing fine. `24302MB` of cache which is also fine. All modern major OSes (read) cache as much as your RAM allows.

Comment: Nothing is able to use it. If it tries, the entire system drops, as only about 2 GB of that available RAM is actually open.

Comment: Are you running any graphical applications? Some GPUs use your RAM as VRAM. I'm not sure if the kernel counts everything properly in this case. Please edit your question and post `free -m` output and `df -T` output.

Comment: Yes, my iGPU only has 96 MB of actual VRAM, so *any* application uses RAM this way. However, this occurs before the VRAM allco is bumped up to fit more data. Once my phone is done, I can take a video of the disaster that occurs. All I have to do is have KDE look for a file, kills it every time due to buffering.

Comment: Check out [OOMPolicy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#OOMPolicy=), [OOMScoreAdjust](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) and [systemd-oomd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-oomd.service.html)